# Intuition for limits computed using polar coordinates

Tags: calculus, limits, polar-coordinates

I would like to understand how can we change from multivariable limit to a limit that only involves r
Because in school they tell me :
$x = cos(\theta)$
$y = sin(\theta)$
$r^2 = x^2 +y^2$  so as $(x,y) \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}$ we have $r\to 0^+$
I learn this and I just do it mechanical. But I would like to see why this is true. And  somewhere, I have seen that if the function depends on $x$ and $y$, i.e. $f(x,y)$ then when doing the change of variable to polar coordinates we get $f(r, \theta)$. However, when writing down the limit in polar coordinates, we only put as $r\to 0^+$, where do we leave the theta and why? Why shouldn't it be as $(r,\theta)\to (a,b)$
where $a$, $b$ belong to $\Bbb R$?
Thanks a lot !

Comment: $r \rightarrow 0^{+}$ is the same thing as $x,y \rightarrow 0.  \theta$ would matter if it were anywhere but the origin, but it is, so if $r \rightarrow 0$, then you get to the origin no matter what happens to $\theta$, like circling a drain.

Comment: And can I approach to the origin in another way which doesn't imply  letting r--> 0+ ? Thanks!